# SQL query not selecting property

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query like this
[image]

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     `GSheets` 
WHERE    `sheetcat` = 'Unsubscribed' 
AND      `sheetcat` IS NOT NULL 
AND      `user` LIKE '%,r00t,%' 
OR       `user` LIKE 'r00t,%' 
OR       '%,r00t' 
OR       `user` = 'r00t'
```

I specify sheetcat to be Unsubscribed, but query response is NULL (or blank)?
Why?

Comment: You probably want some parentheses in the WHERE clause... (Hint: user likes...)

Comment: Thanks to moderators who fix my post, and all other for helping me posting better content with irony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem when you store lists of things in delimited strings.  Bad, bad, bad data design.  The first and primary advice is to create a new table with one row per sheet and one row per user.

Now, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really bad, bad, bad design decisions.  MySQL offers `find_in_set()` which does what you want:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM `GSheets` g
WHERE `sheetcat` = 'Unsubscribed' AND
      FIND_IN_SET('r00t', `user`) > 0;
```

Note that `sheetcat IS NOT NULL` is redundant.  A `NULL` value would fail the first condition.  Unless you possibly intend:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM `GSheets` g
WHERE `sheetcat` = 'Unsubscribed' OR
      (sheetcat IS NOT NULL AND FIND_IN_SET('r00t', `user`) > 0);
```

But that would not be my first guess as to your intention.

Your query would also work if you put parentheses around the `OR` conditions.  But even that is too complicated.  A simpler version using `LIKE` would be:

```
WHERE `sheetcat` = 'Unsubscribed' AND
       CONCAT(',', `user`, ',') LIKE '%,r00t,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

[`AND` takes precedence over `OR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms190276.aspx).  You need to group your `OR` conditions:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     `GSheets` 
WHERE    `sheetcat` = 'Unsubscribed' 
AND      
(        `user` LIKE '%,r00t,%' 
OR       `user` LIKE 'r00t,%' 
OR       `user` LIKE '%,r00t' 
OR       `user` = 'r00t'
)
```

The second `sheetcat` condition is also redundant, you can remove the `NULL` check.